# LU Decomposition Determinant Mismatch Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matlab, lu-decomposition

I'm trying to get the determinant of a matrix by LU factorization.

I have the following matrix:

```
a = [2 4 2;
    1 5 2;
    4 -1 9];
```

When I execute the command **det(a)** in matlab, it shows the determinant to be **48**. Then I enter the decomposition command:

```
[L, U, P] = lu(a)
```

It shows the matrix **L** to be:

```
1.0000         0         0
0.2500    1.0000         0
0.5000    0.8571    1.0000
```

and the matrix **U** to be:

```
4.0000   -1.0000    9.0000
     0    5.2500   -0.2500
     0         0   -2.2857
```

As we know that the determinant of a matrix is also the product of the principal diagonal elements of it's **U** matrix after the decomposition, it doesn't match up in this case. Because the product of the diagonal elements of the matrix **U** is **-47.999**. But it shouldn't have been a negative number.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's that matrix $P$ that lu gives you?  It's the permutation matrix in the $PA = LU$ factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$LU=PA$$

$$\det(L) \det(U) = \det(P) \det(A)$$

$$\det(A) = \det(P) \det(U)$$

since $\det(L)=1$.

$\det(P)=-1$ for this example.